# dojo.form.datetextbox change default year

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

i am using dojo.form.datetextbox to generate the calender in which i use the constraints for user to select only selected years , it works fine but i want to show only the those year which is valid i.e between selected year ,, but calender is show me the year from current .. 
 i am using following code.. of constraints

```
function setmax(){
            var w = dijit.byId('dob');
            w.constraints.datePattern='dd-MM-yyyy';
            w.constraints.max= new Date(1947,08,15);
            w.constraints.min= new Date(1987,1,1);

            w.set('value', w.get('value')); // reformat display to short year
        }
        dojo.ready(setmax);
```

please help me to show years from 1987  ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about:

```
    function setmax(){
        var w = dijit.byId('dob');
        w.constraints.datePattern='dd-MM-yyyy';
        w.constraints.max= new Date(1987,1,1);
        w.constraints.min= new Date(1947,08,15);

        w.set('value', new Date(1987,1,1)); // reformat display to short year
    }
    dojo.ready(setmax);
```

also not shure about this, but aren't your min and max constraints inverted?